# Requesting feedback on Version 2 of beeJACK company logo

Tags: logo, critique

Taking into consideration feedback from initial question I am uploading version 2. outlined the bee's body in black and changed the stripes to yellow to help with the visual of a bee. I also used gradient so I could incorporate purple into the head and wings. Also utilized some gray gradients. You will see the head and body have a small shadow which I added to give it depth or dimension.

I'm not a graphic design person and did the best I could. I figure if I can get the design nailed down that it will be easier for someone to take the logo over the finished line.

I'd like to ask if anyone knows where I can find a graphic design student looking for a class project.

Let me know if there are any questions, and thank you again for taking time to provide feedback.

Best
[image]

Comment: I liked your original concept slightly more.

Comment: Readability of one E is affected by that stroke. And green color isn't quite fitting with this color scheme. The grey gradient in middle body of bee could be inverted.

Comment: And those antennas are also getting mixed with wings.

Comment: Quite apart from being anatomically incorrect, that massively oversized stinger is quite off-putting to me. Unless you’re a company that makes needles, a huge, sharp stinger that looks like it’s about to cause you significant pain is not something that’s likely to instil positive thoughts in your mind.

Comment: You want to draw a shape which can be associated with a bee. Not the usual diligent and maybe  playful bee, but a strong and dangerous one. The strength of real bees is their well focused co-operation. You can try to present it. An example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIr1I.png

Answer (score 2):

Barring any comments on the aesthetics, here may be few *technical* tips...

- **Kill the shadows.** They are simply a *bad* idea for *any* logo.
- **Gradients** are something which you should **not** use until you have solid black and white artwork. *Then* you can worry about color.
- I'd also point out that logos need to work at 100px wide as well as 2Ft wide. 
  While not horrendous, this art is not maintained well smaller sizes in a single color. 
  [image]
  And possibly a bit worse in color
  [image]

Look at logos from companies you like. You'll discover none use shadows and few, if any, will rely upon gradients to separate elements.

Finding a student may be wise, if not hiring a professional. There is actually *a lot* which goes into developing a mark that will last for years and work well. Logo development is certainly *not* "rocket science", by any means. However, like anything, the more professional you want the end result to be, the more you need someone educated in areas of consideration which often go unnoticed by those not educated. Some companies have no issue using a logo created by a third cousin with no experience... others want more. Only you can determine what level you want to display to the public.